# Detect JavaScript-Banners, which have been removed by Adblock Plus

Tags: detect, banner, banner-ads

AdBlock Plus uses MozBinding to show, that a Banner has been removed. Unfortunately, this isn't the case for JavaScript banner's. There, Adblock Plus just removes the source code, which will load the banner.

Someone out there who came across this problem & maybe has an solution or an idea?

Comment: What's the problem?  ;-).  People who use Adblock Plus don't want to see JavaScript banner ads.  They certainly don't want sites trying to defeat the extension.

Comment: Yes, basically i have to agree with you! But was just wondering, why adblock plus provides some technics to detect removed banners but no javascript banners...